# ffmpeg won't ./configure in iOS5.1

Tags: iphone, c, ios, ffmpeg

I am trying to build ffmpeg on iOS5.1 (armv7), when I try to run ./configure like this:

```
./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver
   --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin
   --cc=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
   --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc'
   --sysroot=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
   --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7'
   --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk'
   --enable-pic
```

I get the following error:

```
/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.
```

> If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
>   version from SVN.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
>   ffmpeg-user@mplayerhq.hu mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
>   Include the log file "config.err" produced by configure as this will help
>   solving the problem.

Could somebody please provide the correct parameters in iOS5.1?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 4):

the instructions have changed since there is no longer a `gcc` in the xcode SDK.

What you need to do is specify that cc is the iphoneos compiler using xcrun, so where we previously just put the path to `gcc`, we're now going to put a reference to `xcrun` for `clang`.

I downloaded the latest ffmpeg from git, made sure I had a copy of gas-preprocess.pl on the path, and then changed the `--cc=` line to read:

```
--cc='xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -mios-version-min=5.1'
```

(this assumes you're building and still targetting ios 5.1 - if you're targetting newer, then you change the value to the newer release. I specified 7.0 for mine, but I'm also using the iOS 8.4 SDK, so the configure line looks like:

```
./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver \
 --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin \
 --cc='xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -mios-version-min=7.0' \
 --sysroot=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk \
 --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' \
 --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk' \
 --enable-pic
```

which builds ffmpeg from the ios8.4 SDK. These instructions should keep working; you just need to replace the appropriate `7.0`/`8.4` values for the newer SDKs.

**OLD ANSWER**

That's what happens when you try to compile iOS code using the MacOS version of the compiler.

You need to specify the iPhoneOS version of gcc using:

```
./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver
   --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin
   --cc=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
   --as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc'
   --sysroot=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
   --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7'
   --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7
   -isysroot /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk'
   --enable-pic
```

The first step when trying to debug problems with `configure` is to look at the `config.log` file which is generated as part of the run.

Comment: upon running the modified command I get this in the config.log: 
llvm-gcc-4.2: Invalid arch name : armv7 --extra-ldflags=-arch
C compiler test failed.

Comment: Since the latest Xcode versions (Eg. 6.4) are not having gcc in the given location (/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc) what shall we do?

Comment: Considering these instructions are for iOS5, I'm not surprised things have changed. I'll update the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things wrong with your configure script, that I can tell. First of all, you are using:

```
--cc=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
```

This is wrong. You should be using the architecture specific gcc compilers, so in your case (armv7) you should be using, for example:

```
--cc=/applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1
```

Notice you're calling upon the `arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1` version of apple's own gcc.
Since this is only an example, look in your `../Developer/../bin/` and use the latest `arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-x.x.x` that you have. I see that there are a lot of answers on SO that suggest you do it the way you have done it, this is just flat out wrong! and doesn't work for arm, it'll work for i386 (simulator) only.

You will need to update the assembler directive to reflect using the same gcc version:

```
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1'
```

Additionally, don't put an `-arch armv7` in your `--extra-cflags`, you may get an 
`error: unrecognized command line option "-arch"`

Lastly and depending on your situation, might I suggest the following, in addition to what you already have:

```
--disable-bzlib --disable-gpl --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-mmx --disable-debug --disable-neon
```

and change to this:

```
--extra-cflags='-pipe -Os -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -m${thumb_opt:-no-thumb} -mthumb-interwork'
```

Hope this helps.