# Compiling ffmpeg for iOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, compilation, ffmpeg

I followed jold's steps from here:

[problem compiling ffmpeg for iFrameExtractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994151/problem-compiling-ffmpeg-for-iframeextractor/12369821#12369821)

When i try jold's solution i get the following error for armv6 and armv7. i386 works perfect.

> lipo: can't open input file: armv6/libavcodec.a (No such file or directory)
>
> lipo: can't open input file: armv6/libavutil.a (No such file or directory
>
> lipo: can't open input file: armv6/libswscale.a (No such file or directory)

When the script ends i have only libadevice.a and libavformat.a in /armv7 and /armv6.

Why?

Comment: Note that putting an iOS app with ffmpeg compiled into it in the store is a murky legal issue: http://multinc.com/2009/08/24/compatibility-between-the-iphone-app-store-and-the-lgpl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer:
The reason is because the IframeExtractor build script is wrong. The arm versions of ffmpeg never actually gets built because the script errors out during the build. You can see the error happen during ./configure

See my answer to the same question here:

[ffmpeg won't ./configure in iOS5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982528/ffmpeg-wont-configure-in-ios5-1/10066116#10066116)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using an older than latest version of ffmpeg, but one well tested that works very well with armv7 devices you can try this.

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group

when we get around to it we will update to version 11, but we find .8 has fewer issues and better video.